# How do I configure Flyway in Grails3 / Postgres?

Tags: grails, flyway

I am trying to use Flyway to run migrations for my Grails 3.2.8 application. According to https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/grails one should just need to add a dependency to build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.1.2"
}
```

As I want Flyway to generate my schema I have also edited application.yml to not have domain object generated. If I do not have this setting Grails will generate my tables - not Flyway.

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
```

I have also added a migration file to:

```
grails-app
  conf
    db
      migration
        V1__create_tables.sql
```

I also read here (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) that some extra configuration could done so I added this to application.yml:

```
flyway:
  enabled: true
  locations: classpath:grails-app/conf/db/migration
  sql-migration-prefix: V
  sql-migration-suffix: .sql
```

I have also tried without any of my added configurations. I seem to be missing something?

Comment: could you try changing `locations: classpath:grails-app/conf/db/migrate` to `locations: grails-app/conf/db/migrate`

Comment: The @erichelgeson that writes "Practical Grails 3"? In that case I like the update I received today. :-)  Thank you for your suggestion, but it did not help. When I run the application I expect Flyway to run the migration, but the migration is not run.

Comment: The same - I'd then try to move it out of grails-app completely. Though I've not used Flyway it seems most users put it under src or different location. Have a look at https://github.com/saw303/grails-flyway as well - they setup the beans manually - you may want to see if your beans are created.

Comment: Yes, that would make it more like how it works in Rails. Grails have a lot of nice preconfigured stuff built in, but db migrations are definitely missing in the tool box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

spring-boot auto-configuration of flyway relies by default on one single `DataSource` bean being available at the time of auto-configuration.

ref. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration.java#L130

however, that is not the case if gorm defines the grails `DataSource` - that happens after boot autoconfig.

one possible solution is to define an "alias" `DataSource` bean that acts as the flyway dataSource, delegating to the gorm/grails defined one.

```
@Configuration
class FlywayConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource

    @Bean
    @FlywayDataSource
    DataSource flywayDataSource() {
        return dataSource
    }

}
```

sample: check https://github.com/zyro23/stackoverflow-43211960/commit/c4063c900b7f96bc9ba65c84684a14a1992ca2a5

visiting http://localhost:8080/dbconsole (`jdbc:h2:mem:devDb`) you should see that the `TEST` table has been created.

Comment: Very nice answer. These instructions need to be added to https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/grails.

Comment: Thanks zyro. If you could help out a dummy?  How would the code be adapted for multiple datasources?