# Grails 3.2.x with Flyway

Tags: grails, flyway

I'm finding the available information about using Flyway with later (3.2.9) versions of Grails somewhat confusing.

There is a grails-flyway plugin that was around in Grails 2 days. It has been migrated to Grails 3. The Grails Documentation [4.4.2 Automatic Database Migration](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#automaticDatabaseMigration) has a Flyway link to [org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway](https://grails.org/plugins.html#plugin/org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway), the Grails Flyway plugin.

But, the Flyway documentation [for Grails 3](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/grails) says "Grails 3.x is based on Spring Boot comes with out-of-the-box integration for Flyway." All we have to do is include a reference to Flyway in build.gradle.

And there is an article [Flyway with Grails 3](http://krisrichardson.com/flyway-with-grails-3/#comments) by Kris Richardson that describes how to use Flyway with Grails 3 and no mention  of the grails-flyway plugin in sight. Kris does describe that it isn't quite so simple and we need to define a bean in spring resources.groovy, but I think that's more to do with automatic DB migration.

Can someone clarify the current state of play regarding using Flyway with the later (3.2+) versions of Grails? Do I need the plugin, or not?

How can I make change the automatic migration behaviour different per environment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211960/how-do-i-configure-flyway-in-grails3-postgres/43214863#43214863

Comment: You can do it without the plugin, however the plugin makes it easier.